# What happens when a float is cast to/from a boolean at the first principle level?

Tags: python, c, cpython

I'm trying to figure out what really happens under the hood when a float is cast to/from a bool in python. Here is the information I could find online and I was wondering if anyone else would be willing to step in and help me get an official understanding:

**floats** are represented in C as a 64-bit data structure and known as a double.

**booleans** are represented in C as 1's and 0's. If *true* -> 1 (binary form 0001) if *false* -> 0 (binary form 0000).

From [this link here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Double-precision_floating-point_format), I can see that there are really 3 parts to a *double* in memory. The sign, exponent, and fraction.

Working up from first principles I'm inclined to think that some combination of the exponent and fraction are used to be cast to float to boolean. For example `2^0` is `1` but `e^x != 0` for all permutations of `e` and `x` respectively, so I'm really confused.

I have an interview tomorrow that is most likely going to ask me this question so I'm wondering if I could get some help figuring this out. Thanks and have a great day/night!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the relevant code from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c.

```
static int
float_bool(PyFloatObject *v)
{
    return v->ob_fval != 0.0;
}
```

As we can see, the value v->ob_fval (a double) is compared to 0.0.  If they compare unequal, the function returns a non-zero value, which Python then maps to the bool value True (or 1).  If they compare equal, the function returns 0 (false), which Python maps to the bool value False (0).

So the question of how double is represented isn't really relevant at the level of the Python interpreter.  The expression `v->ob_fval != 0.0` will most likely map to a single hardware compare instruction.  Most processors have dedicated hardware for floating point operations.

Comparing to 0 is slightly tricky, because IEEE floating point numbers have both a +0 and -0 representation (as you can see in the link you provided), so the hardware needs to check for the case where v->ob_fval is -0, but being compared to +0.  But the hardware typically takes care of that, without Python (or even the C compiler) generally having to worry about that level of detail.

Your confusion about `2^0` and `e^x` isn't really relevant to the original question, but I think you are definitely confused, so I'd suggest reading your link again.  The key is that the exponent in the double is not the exponent of the fractional part; it's the exponent of the constant value 2, and the fraction (plus 1) is multiplied by the result.

Comment: @chux: When I test in clang, both of them evaluate to 1, and in Python bool(float("nan")) evaluates to True, so everything seems consistent to me.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the internal representation of a `float`.

Booleans are a subclass of `int`, so `float(True) == 1.0` and `float(False) == 0.0`.

Only 0.0 maps to `False`; all other floating-point values (including `float("nan")` and `float("inf")`) map to `True`.

Comment: "Only 0.0"? There are two, +0.0 and -0.0. :-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, I'm don't think CPython assumes that will be true.

Answer (score 0):

In C

Converting a `float` to `bool`:

`+0.0f, -0.0f` --> `false`, all else `float`, including not-a-numbers, are `true`.

Internal `float` representation is irrelevant , only its *value*.

> When any scalar value is converted to `_Bool`, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1  C11 §6.3.1.2 1

---

Converting a `bool` to `float`:

`false` --> `0.0f`, `true` --> `1.0f`

> An object declared as type `_Bool` is large enough to store the values 0 and 1.  §6.2.5 2