# Logical operation with float number (with C & python)

Tags: floating-point, boolean, decimal, logical-operators, operation

I'm a Python newbie and currently comparing python with C language using logical operations.

My question is

(I could solve Q1 (logical operation in C), thank you for your comments!)

Q1: Logical operation in C

Why 0.7 && 0.7 is not 1 in c code?
I expected it to be "true", since

```
(bool)0.7 is 1 and (bool)0.8 is 1 // This is what I meant, revised after checking the comments, Thank you!
```

because 0.7 and 0.8 are non-zero values.

Q2: Logical operation in Python

Why 0.7 and 0.7 is not computed out in a boolean type in Python?
Is this because of dynamic programming?

Would you please let me know?

Thank you in advance.

---

In detail,from both python and c codes:

I expected

> `0.7&&0.7` # equal to 1

. Likewise,

> `0.8&&0.8` # equal to 1

But what I got from both compiler was:

From Python

```
 0.7 and 0.7
 Out[46]: 0.7

 0.8 and 0.8
 Out[47]: 0.8
```

From C with the code below:

```
 int main()
 {
     double a = 0.8;
     double b = 0.8;
     printf("%f AND %f is %f", a, b, a&&b);

     return 0;
  }
```

the output was : 0.800000 AND 0.800000 is 0.000000

and with a=0.7, b=0.7
The result is same. (0.800000 AND 0.800000 is 0.000000)

Comment: [Check Out This Previous Post, Explains it All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600928/what-happens-when-a-float-is-cast-to-from-a-boolean-at-the-first-principle-level) And in python 1.0 is The Float For True and 0.0 for false

Comment: You are passing an `int` where `printf` expects a `double`. I suggest to always enable compiler warnings (at least `-Wall` on gcc/clang): https://godbolt.org/z/df1EME

Comment: N.B.: `0.7&&0.7==1` would evaluate to `0.7&&(0.7==1)` which evaluates to false (or `0` in C).

Answer (score 0):

I could solve Q1 (logical operation in C), thank you for your comments!

Any advice to understand the logical operation in Python that computes "0.7 and 0.7" as 0.7 not 1 (or True)?

Python:

```
 0.7 and 0.7
 Out[46]: 0.7
```

not

```
 0.7 and 0.7
 Out[46]: 1 #or true
```

(It seems to be important when writing conditional expression in Python..)

---

Concerning Q2, I could solve it with your help:

After changing %f to %d, I could get 1 (true) from 0.7&&0.7 which I expected.

```
 int main()
 {
     double a = 0.8;
     double b = 0.8;
     printf("%f AND %f is %d", a, b, a&&b);

     return 0;
  }
```